# Hostname was not match with the server certificate while opening pdf with prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, prawn

I'm using prawn to build pdfs. I'm having some trouble opening an existing pdf uploaded to Amazon S3. I've got a model called `Format` which has a `file_name` attribute which has an associated uploader.

When I try to open the existing pdf as a template:

```
pdf.start_new_page(:template => open(@format.file_name_url))
```

The following error occurs:

```
hostname was not match with the server certificate
```

When I go to `@format.file_name_url` myself, I don't have any issues, which means the URL is correct. What is going on? Thanks!

Comment: What does your `file_name_url` look like? Is it something like `https://yourdomain.s3.amazonaws.com/blah/filename.pdf` ?